# How to do tagging of faces like facebook with face recognition azure

Tags: swift, azure, azure-cognitive-services

I want to **detect the faces from the picture and display the names of the person on that image,** Currently, I am using [Microsoft Azure](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/services/cognitive-services/face/) face recognition. It detects faces with default behaviour like age, gestures, and other. but the scenario is to displays the name of person.

Please Explain the steps that I have to take.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the link for the Face API documentation
https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/563879b61984550e40cbbe8d/operations/563879b61984550f30395239
As they say at first you have to create a collection of faces in the storage and if you want to recognize face in image at first you need to send an image and get the response with detected face, after that you have to send detected face and get the response  in which will be the faceID of the recognized face so you will know the person with his faceID

Comment: Could you please give more explanation? also how to add the collection of faces in their storage?

Comment: First creating a face list 
https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/563879b61984550e40cbbe8d/operations/563879b61984550f3039524b
you have to specify some faceListID and create a faceList request body and responses explained in link below
Second add face to face list
https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/563879b61984550e40cbbe8d/operations/563879b61984550f30395250
You have to send an image of some person and you will get the response in which will be the persistedFaceId generated by API

Comment: If you want to find similar face with exciting image you have to
First send your image for face detection https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/563879b61984550e40cbbe8d/operations/563879b61984550f30395236 in response you will get the faceID
Second you have to send request for finding similar face with given faceID
https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/563879b61984550e40cbbe8d/operations/563879b61984550f30395237

Comment: By the way my advice to you to use Amazon face recognition api its more easy and also it has the sdk for ios

Comment: thanks, Arman I appreciate with this I will definitely look Amazon face recognition.!

Comment: Aman here after some analysis we got that we can add max 1000 face in the list so how to identify the other faces?
Also, If I am creating the group so how could I know which group has the same person face?